# Stock clustering based on fundamental reporting

Tags: clustering, feature-selection, feature-engineering, finance

I want to made a stock clusterization, based on their fundamental features from companies quarter reports.

I collected quarter reports from 2018 to 2022. Some companies have reports for all quarters of all years, some publish reports twice a year..

So, before data preprocessing and clustering itself, I need to understand how my data will look like. That is my question. I have data from 2018 to 2022 and I, in my opinion, need to aggregate it to describe stocks. What options do I have? If I find only mean values of each feature for each company, I will lose a lot of information.

Options that I have come up with:

1. Cluster companies by years
2. Summarize data for each company, but compute not only mean, but also median, std, max/min and so on.

Thanks in advance for advice!